# selenium-webdriver click the first link

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium-webdriver and i'm looking for something really simple but I didn't find it in the documentation.

This is a part of my code :

```
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
browser.navigate.to 'an_url'
# I find ancestor element
browser.find_element(:id, "displaylinks").find_element(:id, "link0").find_element(:class, "link-center")
# but I want to click the first link child of this last element
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of different selectors that you could use:

```
ancestor_element = browser.find_element(:id, "displaylinks").find_element(:id, "link0").find_element(:class, "link-center")

#Using tag_name
ancestor_element.find_element(:tag_name, 'a').click

#Using css-selector
ancestor_element.find_element(:css, 'a').click

#Using xpath-selector (direct child)
ancestor_element.find_element(:xpath, './a').click 

#Using xpath-selector (anywhere in ancestor)child)
ancestor_element.find_element(:xpath, './/a').click
```

Comment: Could you please explain the `./a` and `.//a`)? with code i couldn't understand.

Comment: @CodeLover, those are xpath selectors. The first says to find the first 'a' element (ie a link) that is a direct child of the ancestor_element. The second says to find the link anywhere within the ancestor_element. So if you have `<div><span><a>text</a></span></div>`, the first with not find a link while the second one will. For more details, you probably want to read up on xpath selectors.

Comment: `+1` to you.Thank you very much! Any good material on the `xpath` if you want can refer me.

Comment: @CodeLover, the xpath documentation on Location Paths - http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths - is a good place to find out what exists. You can then easily search for examples of specific things.